# is there a "split" function in t-sql for a SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use my function like this

```
SELECT BaseSplit(line,';') FROM table
```

is there any way to do that ???

I try CROSS APPLY but it not what I want

---

My table has a column named line

```
line 
______
15;2;5
NULL
10;3;6
```

I want to split this column to be like

```
15
2
5
Null
10
3
6
```

Is there a string function that does this automatically?
If not, is it possible to write my own function?

Comment: Why isn't `CROSS APPLY` what you want? And what *do* you want then?

Comment: Following your additional information  what does `SELECT f.*  FROM table AS t CROSS APPLY dbo.BaseSplit(line,';') AS f` return? We can't see your function definition. Do you need `OUTER APPLY`?

Comment: it duplicate lines from the table and I want that –

Comment: You want what? Based on the example data you have shown us I can't see a sensible split function would return any duplicate data. Please provide the definition of the function. And example data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It sounds like maybe we still need this function, is that right?  Are you trying to find such a function as "BaseSplit" ?

Comment: @MikeM - Pretty sure that was an invalid edit. They clearly have a custom split function but it isn't doing what they want for reasons that have yet to be fully explained.

Comment: @MartinSmith -  Yes, I see that is the trend in the conversation, that the function exists.  But I'm trying to make a friendly guess that maybe that isn't the case.  Sometimes asking directly is the way to go.

Comment: @MikeM - Well I'm out anyway. 45 minutes after asking and the OP still hasn't managed to properly explain it themselves.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Indeed.  We can only try.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine, but you need to schema-qualify functions.

IE:

```
SELECT dbo.BaseSplit(line,';') FROM table
```

If your function is in a different schema than dbo you should obviously use that instead.

OK - assuming its a table valued function then...

```
SELECT t.Id, f.*  FROM table AS t CROSS APPLY dbo.BaseSplit(line,';') AS f
```

That would return a row for each split line + the ID of the that entry in the main table (assuming a column named Id exists in the main table). If you want better that that I'm going to need an example of what output you expect

Comment: Split function is likely to be a TVF not a scalar UDF.

Comment: It give me that error

Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.udf_wsdn_BaseSplit", or the name is ambiguous. Severity 16

Comment: ah good point. Maybe @user3190075 can give us an example of the expected output, and describe the function BaseSplit (ie confirm if it is a Table Valued or scalar function) Also what is "that error" please?

Comment: I want to split the column line in table  by my function

Comment: @user3190075 - **Show us** example source data and desired results. Your attempts to explain it verbally so far have been sadly lacking.