# Split a String Variable with a specific delimiter into x lines (in SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I am fairly new to SQL Programming and I can't find a solution to a problem I'm having.

I have a table which looks like that

---

```
ID     Var_to_split
---------------------
1      abc, def, ghi
2      jkl
3      mno, pqr
```

---

the output should be

---

```
ID  Var
--------
1   abc
1   def
1   ghi
2   jkl
3   mno
3   pqr
```

---

I don't know how many characters there are in each row I just know that they are delimited by a ','

I found several questions on here to split a String. (eg [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco))

But they all work only with a single string. 
I want it to work within a table for each ID.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a "split" function in t-sql for a SELECT query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165414/is-there-a-split-function-in-t-sql-for-a-select-query)

Comment: Combine the answers you found with [`Table-Valued User-Defined Functions`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) and [`Using APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many questions, I had to pick one to close the question, but none provide a better answer than @AaronBertrand's article on the subject, so although I am voting to close the question as a duplicate, my real advice is read, and probably re-read the article. It should answer all the questions you have.

Comment: Thanks @GarethD. And next read this - because really you shouldn't be storing the data in the database that way, and if you are building that string at insert time, there are better ways all around. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql